# Not able to set request headers to my ajax request

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, rest

I'm trying to make an ajax call to service, my service api expects a Request Header for Authorization to give the response
Here is my JS code

```
var settings = {
       url: "http://localhost:8080/codebluet-war/service/codeblue/facility",
       method: "GET",
       headers: {
           "Authorization": "oauthtoken"",
       }
   }
$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response)
});
```

I have added the Authorization headers in my code but still I'm getting 401 unauthorized request error.is there any other thing that I need to add in my settings?

Comment: it's typo i think remove "Authorization": "oauthtoken"" <---- totally oauthtoken is a variable but it is assigned as string

Comment: I have just typed ouathtocken in stead of my actual oauth token

Answer (score 1):

If you are using OAuth 2.0 you should prefix the token value with [Bearer](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750#page-5) word:

```
headers: {
    "Authorization": "Bearer yourTokenValue",
}
```

With OAuth 1.0, it's a little bit more complicated since you need to send a [set of parameters](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5849#page-27) instead of a single token. Therefore, you may want to consider using a [jQuery compatible OAuth library](https://github.com/ddo/oauth-1.0a#work-with-jqueryajax-browser) for this purpose.

Comment: I'm using Oauth 1.0 @antonku